# Store a data member on heap memory

Tags: c++, memory

when a local variable is initialized it is created on the stack. Can we create a local variable on heap memory? If so, what are the different ways in which we can do the same?

I am using c++

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: i want to do it in c++

Comment: Well you can create something on the heap and get a pointer to it. If you declare the pointer in a local scope that'd be local. Essentially you'll have a value on the heap and a pointer on the stack that points to the heap. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you initialize a local variable it gets memory from stack.
But if you want to initialize some local variable and use heap memory then use concept of [`Dynamic Memory Allocation`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_dynamic_memory.htm) like this:

```
int *foo;
foo = new int [5];
```

This will initialize a `int pointer` in stack but it will point to some memory location in `heap` which you can use to store your `foo` array.

Check [this](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/lectures/slides_cpp_dynamic-memory.php) out for more understanding.